# Why does not HttpClient work in BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Here is the code

```
static BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Result);
}

public static async void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    string httpResult = await client.GetStringAsync("http://ozgurakpinar.net/androidserver.aspx?param=accenture2");
    e.Result = httpResult;
}
```

It waits forever in GetStringAsync line. However it works when I use thread instead of BackgroundWorker.

Comment: I'm not sure that an async void DoWork is a good idea

Comment: What do you mean by "It waits forever in GetStringAsync line."? You application hung? As I see, you code have race condition: it can print results before string retrieved from web server.

Comment: @PetSerAl Shouldn't it "await" until I get the result from server?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Then how can I achieve such a simple task? Threads are difficult for me to handle callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your misunderstandings:

1. `async void` returns immediately causing `BackgroundWorker` to think the work is done. `BackgroundWorker` is obsolete with await. Delete all of that.
2. `BackgroundWorker` makes no sense in a console application. It is a component made for UIs.

It's actually quite simple when you throw out all the unneeded stuff:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.ReadLine(worker_DoWork().Result); //intentionally blocking here
}

static async Task<string> worker_DoWork()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    string httpResult = await client.GetStringAsync("http://ozgurakpinar.net/androidserver.aspx?param=accenture2");
    return httpResult;
}
```

Async and threading are dangerous tools. Use when required, not by default.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation in number 1. It helped a lot. Number 2 is also helpful because Threads in console application do not need a handler to access Console.Writeline(). But in this case I still need a thread because I do not want to wait (even though it is a console app) until request is done.

Comment: OK, then simply do not call Result which blocks. I have only done that to keep the Main thread alive which is required for the process to not exit.